# Black not formatting Python code from VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am trying to work with Python in VSCode and recently got to know about 'black' code formatter. It works fine in my work laptop. But in personal laptop, it does not auto-format code even though they have the exact same settings.

I am pasting my VSCode settings here just for reference:

```
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
"python.linting.enabled": true,
"python.linting.flake8Args": [
    "--max-line-length=100",
    "--ignore=E501"
],
"python.formatting.provider": "black",
"python.formatting.blackArgs": [
    "--line-length",
    "100"
],
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"[python]": {
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.organizeImports": true
    }
}
```

Now I have been trying to debug the issue and found that if I try to import black in my virtual env, it is giving some AttributeError.

```
>>> import black
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "src\black\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\hangman_test\venv\lib\site-packages\black\files.py", line 27, in <module>
    from black.handle_ipynb_magics import jupyter_dependencies_are_installed
  File "src\black\handle_ipynb_magics.py", line 51, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'secrets' has no attribute 'token_hex'
```

I don't understand why this error is coming. I tried googling also but didn't find anything. Any help or pointing to the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just putting it here in case it helps somebody, the error comes because my project had a file called `secrets.py`. So when black tries to find secrets module of Python, it finds my `secrets.py`, which does not have many attributes that in-built secrets module have.

I just had to rename the file `secrets.py` to something else and the issue is resolved.